# Names of instances and loading objects from a database

Tags: python, oop

I got for example the following structure of a class.

```
class Company(object):
    Companycount = 0

    _registry = {}

    def __init__(self, name):

        Company.Companycount +=1
        self._registry[Company.Companycount] = [self]

        self.name = name

k = Company("a firm")
b = Company("another firm")
```

Whenever I need the objects I can access them by using

```
Company._registry
```

which gives out a dictionary of all instances.

Do I need reasonable names for my objects since the name of the company is a class attribute, and I can iterate over `Company._registry`?

When loading the data from the database does it matter what the name of the instance (here `k` and `b`) is? Or can I just use arbitrary strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `Company._registry` and the names `k` and `b` are just *references* to your actual instances. Neither play any role in what you'd store in the database.

Python's object model has all objects living on a big heap, and your code interacts with the objects via such references. You can make as many references as you like, and objects automatically are deleted when there are no references left. See the excellent [*Facts and myths about Python names and values* article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

You need to decide, for yourself, if the `Company._registry` structure needs to have names or not. Iteration over a list is slow if you already have a name for a company you wanted to access, but a dictionary gives you instant access.

If you are going to use an ORM, then you don't really need that structure *anyway*. Leave it to the ORM to help you find your objects, or give you a sequence of all objects to iterate over. I recommend using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for this.

Answer (score -1):

the name doesn't matter but if you are gonna initialize a lot of objects you are still gonna make it reasonable somehow